# How to move a turtle in Python using if-else and else statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, turtle-graphics

Need help creating my turtle and then moving it with commands using if-else and else statements in Python using Turtle Graphics. Don't know how to start

Comment: https://realpython.com/beginners-guide-python-turtle/

Comment: Well, you have to present at least something to base an answer on. And you have to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm horrible at explaining things, so I'll just give you an example. I hope you understand it.

```
import turtle 
import time

a = 1
b = 2

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("If, Elif, Else Statements")
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

if a > b:
    a1 = turtle.Turtle()
    a1.speed(0)
    a1.shape("square")
    a1.color("white")
    a1.penup()
    a1.hideturtle()
    a1.goto(0,260)
    a1.write("If Statement = True", align = "center", font = ("ds-digital", 24, "normal"))
    time.sleep(10)

elif a < b:
    a2 = turtle.Turtle()
    a2.speed(0)
    a2.shape("square")
    a2.color("white")
    a2.penup()
    a2.hideturtle()
    a2.goto(0,260)
    a2.write("Elif Statement = True", align = "center", font = ("ds-digital", 24, "normal"))
    time.sleep(10)

else:
    a3 = turtle.Turtle()
    a3.speed(0)
    a3.shape("square")
    a3.color("white")
    a3.penup()
    a3.hideturtle()
    a3.goto(0,260)
    a3.write("Else Statement = True", align = "center", font = ("ds-digital", 24, "normal"))
    time.sleep(10)
```